# Geometry nodes: how to apply the (quick?) explode effect

Tags: geometry-nodes

I love the quick explode effect, and its simplicity (just click `Object > Quick effects > Quick explode` on a simple icosphere). However, I can't find how to apply it to a mesh created using Geometry Nodes:

[image]

**Right**: normal icosphere

**Left**: icosphere created using this simple geometry node:

[image]

Any idea what I'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all make sure that the order of modifiers is correct:

1. *GeometryNodes*
2. *ParticleSystem*
3. *Explode*

Then you have to enable *Use Modifier Stack* in the *Source* settings of the particle system.

[image: explode modifier]

Comment: Amazing, thanks a lot!

Comment: Also, if your note is calling some other nodes inside or instances, you may need to add a "realize instances" node.

Comment: Yes, of course. But since you asked for your icosphere and explicitly showed the nodetree while emphasizing the simplicity of the _Quick Effect_, I just focused on the given geometry. To work on the mesh outside the GN modifier all instances always have to be realized, not only for the _Explode_ modifier but others as well. But since it's not always necessary and sometimes even counterproductive I didn't mention it for your specific problem.

Comment: Oh, it was not any sort of critism. Just a note for myself in the future (and potentially others) because I had this very same problem and I lost 2-3mn to find out what was the issue (and as I'm still new to GN, it's not something that I'm yet used to).

Comment: @tobiasBora No problem, I didn't take it as criticism. I just explained that because there was just another question yesterday where it was unclear what exactly the goal was, and depending on the desired result it made a big difference in nodes order and using _Realize Instances_ or not to achieve one or the other thing.